# How to install homebrew on Ubuntu inside Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, homebrew

When I try to [install](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux#install) homebrew on Ubuntu 18.04

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential curl file git -y
RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

getting errors:

> ==> Add Ruby to your PATH by running: PATH=/root/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/current/bin:$PATH
>   Don't run this as root!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want this?  The Ubuntu package repositories tend to be pretty complete and you can usually `apt-get install` whatever your application’s dependencies are without trouble.  You don’t generally need an extra package manager.

Comment: @DavidMaze The reasons are easier to maintain and read Dockerfile. I can do what I need with one-line brew command instead of several commands with apt-get install like `brew install composer`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxbrew/linuxbrew) (`docker pull linuxbrew/linuxbrew`)? It is based on Ubuntu 16.04 / Xenial.

If you must use Bionic (18.04), the correct way to install homebrew will be to follow the steps in the official [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxbrew/linuxbrew/dockerfile).

But to get your Dockerfile working, you need to install ruby, create a non-root user and execute the installation script as that user. Like so,

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install build-essential curl file git ruby-full locales --no-install-recommends -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash linuxbrew && \
    echo 'linuxbrew ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >>/etc/sudoers

USER linuxbrew
RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"

USER root
ENV PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:${PATH}"
```

PS: I have added `--no-install-recommends` to ignore optional dependencies and `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` to remove `apt-get` leftovers thus reducing the image size. Also, `locales` is added to install UTF-8 or `brew` will throw a warning when you run the command.

Comment: The URL has changed slightly.
Warning: Linuxbrew has been merged into Homebrew.
Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Answer (score 7):

The new correct way is:

```sh
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -q --allow-unauthenticated \
    git \
    sudo
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/zsh linuxbrew && \
    usermod -aG sudo linuxbrew &&  \
    mkdir -p /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && \
    chown -R linuxbrew: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
USER linuxbrew
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 6):

Gabriel's answer mostly worked for me, but was missing one step. I needed to `chown` the `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew` folder to the user that would be running Homebrew:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -q --allow-unauthenticated \
    git \
    sudo
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/zsh linuxbrew && \
    usermod -aG sudo linuxbrew &&  \
    mkdir -p /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && \
    chown -R linuxbrew: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
USER linuxbrew
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

USER root
RUN chown -R $CONTAINER_USER: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
```

Comment: Would you consider copy/pasting Gabriel's answer into your answer, so there is a complete list of the instructions? (It would be easy to see only the "new correct way" comment, and miss the `chown` command...) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers did not work for me on Ubuntu 22.04 Docker container.

I had to add couple of steps
Here's the full code:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -q --allow-unauthenticated \
    git \
    sudo
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/zsh linuxbrew && \
    usermod -aG sudo linuxbrew &&  \
    mkdir -p /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && \
    chown -R linuxbrew: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
USER linuxbrew
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
USER root
RUN chown -R $CONTAINER_USER: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
ENV PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:${PATH}"
RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
USER linuxbrew
RUN brew update
RUN brew doctor
```