How to cache brew bundle install in a Linux Docker container?
I'm trying to cache the Homebrew downloads like I'm doing it for apt packages in the example below. However mounting the cache directory is causing permission errors.
Here is a Dockerfile to reproduce the problem:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM debian:bookworm

# Setup (and cache) the dependencies
RUN rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean; echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/keep-cache
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade --yes \
    && apt-get install --yes \
      sudo=1.9.* \
      curl=7.88.* \
      build-essential=12.9* \
      gcc=4:12.2.* \
      git=1:2.39.*

# Setup the user
RUN sudo adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --shell /bin/bash \
    --home "/home/user" \
    --gecos "User" \
    user
RUN sudo usermod -aG sudo user
RUN echo 'user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

# Setup (and cache) Homebrew
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/77320709
USER root
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash linuxbrew && \
    usermod -aG sudo linuxbrew &&  \
    mkdir -p /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && \
    chown -R linuxbrew: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
USER linuxbrew
RUN /bin/bash -c "NONINTERACTIVE=1 $(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/029184a90aecb8afff8b3ad56a2ea4f1be68cec6/install.sh)"
USER root
RUN sudo chown -R user /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
USER user
ENV PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:${PATH}"
RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
RUN (echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /home/user/.bashrc
RUN eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
RUN brew update-reset
RUN brew doctor
RUN brew cleanup
COPY ./Brewfile /usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile
RUN sudo chown user /usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/user/.cache/Homebrew,sharing=locked \
  HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew bundle install --file=/usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile --verbose --force --cleanup
RUN brew bundle check --file=/usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile
RUN brew analytics off

CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]

Error looks like this:
#25 [stage-0 19/21] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/user/.cache/Homebrew,sharing=locked   HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew bundle install --file=/usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile --verbose --force --cleanup
#25 0.677 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew tap homebrew/bundle
#25 1.319 ==> Tapping homebrew/bundle
#25 1.336 Cloning into '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-bundle'...
#25 2.266 Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/user/.cache/Homebrew/.all_commands_list.txt20240704-183-icgwbm
#25 2.270 Error: Failure while executing; `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew tap homebrew/bundle` exited with 1.
#25 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew bundle install --file=/usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile --verbose --force --cleanup" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [stage-0 19/21] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/user/.cache/Homebrew,sharing=locked   HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew bundle install --file=/usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile --verbose --force --cleanup:
0.677 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew tap homebrew/bundle
1.319 ==> Tapping homebrew/bundle
1.336 Cloning into '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-bundle'...
2.266 Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/user/.cache/Homebrew/.all_commands_list.txt20240704-183-icgwbm
2.270 Error: Failure while executing; `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew tap homebrew/bundle` exited with 1.
------
Dockerfile:48
--------------------
  47 |     RUN sudo chown -R user /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
  48 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/user/.cache/Homebrew,sharing=locked \
  49 | >>>   HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew bundle install --file=/usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile --verbose --force --cleanup
  50 |     RUN brew bundle check --file=/usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew bundle install --file=/usr/local/src/myproject/Brewfile --verbose --force --cleanup" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Things I tried so far:

Mounting like this: --mount=type=cache,target=/home/user/.cache/Homebrew,sharing=locked,mode=0777
Explicitly giving permission to the user: sudo chown -R user /home/user/.cache/Homebrew
Running chmod on the directory

Removing the mount completely eliminates the error.

In Dockerfiles frequently all of the installation will run as root, and you'll only switch to the non-root user at the very end of the file.  Does this approach work for you?  (Also consider cleaning up this Dockerfile to remove the sudo and .bashrc setups, neither of which work well in Docker.)

Not sure about that problem but i do noticeENV PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:${PATH}" here the path may be coming from the host (try $PATH instead) and/or being overriden later on from other configurations like .bashrc
